# Store laser in array then draw 'X' amount of lasers based on current guns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drawing

I am making a first person space shooter game where lasers starting from off screen and shooting to a target location. Been working on a simple solution to do this without canvas and currently I got this : https://jsfiddle.net/Ljhnqkf9/

Some explanation of the code:

```
function adjustLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,lineId) //will rotate the laser properly before it's fired

$laser.animate( //this is the animation code where the laser is traveling to the target
  {
    left: targetX + ( targetW / 2 ),
    top: targetY + (targetH / 2),
    width: "0px"
  },

      complete: function() { //once the animation is completed, restore the laser at starting position (off-screen)

      $laser.css({ left: "0px", top: "0px", width: "100px" });
      $laserBtn.css({
        textShadow:
          "-1px -1px 0 #e5b13a, 1px -1px 0 #e5b13a, -1px 1px 0 #e5b13a, 1px 1px 0 #e5b13a"
      });
    }
```

As you can see I am using the jquery.ui plugin to animate the laser, I like the result, but now when I think about adding multiple lasers (e.g 10 or more) I am stuck at how to do this properly. I was thinking of storing the lasers in array and then draw them in a loop based on the current ship guns, but it always fail at the $laser.animation() part for some reason it doesn't want to accept array or maybe I did something wrong. The idea is to fire 10 lasers at the same time all coming from different locations off-screen and end at the middle of the target as showed on the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create more laser elements and loop through each of them. I created a few for you. You need to also set the initial css for each of the lasers. I created an array for the css objects so you can also reset them from within the animate loop.

I also set the positions of the lasers arbitrarily based on the index of the loop.

I hope this will help you achieve the result you are looking for!

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poller+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="stage">
    <button id="fire-laser" class="fire-laser">Fire Laser</button>
    <div id="laser1" class="laser"></div>
    <div id="laser2" class="laser"></div>
    <div id="laser3" class="laser"></div>
    <div id="laser4" class="laser"></div>
    <div id="ship" class="target"></div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window),
    lasers = [$("#laser1"),$("#laser2"),$("#laser3"),$("#laser4")];
    lasersCss = [];

    $laserBtn = $(".fire-laser");

    var target = document.getElementById("ship");

    var targetW = target.offsetWidth;
    var targetH = target.offsetHeight;

    function getOffset( el ) {
      var _x = 0;
      var _y = 0;
      while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
          _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
          _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
          el = el.offsetParent;
      }
      return { top: _y, left: _x };
    }

    var targetX = getOffset(target).left;
    var targetY = getOffset(target).top;

    function adjustLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,lineId) {
      dist = Math.sqrt( ((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2))    ); 

      x_center = (x1+x2)/2
      y_center = (y1+y2)/2

      rad = Math.atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2)
      deg =  (rad * 180) / Math.PI; 

      lsr = document.getElementById(lineId)
      lsr.style.width = dist
      lsr.style.top = y_center
      lsr.style.left = x_center - (dist/2)
      lsr.style.transform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)"; 
    }

    lasers.forEach((laser, idx) => {
      currentCss = {
        left: '0px',
        top: (idx * 100) + 'px',
        width: '100px'
      };
      laser.css(currentCss);
      lasersCss.push(currentCss);
    });

  $("#fire-laser").click(function() {

      lasers.forEach((laser, idx) => {
      adjustLine(0, 0, targetX, targetY, laser[0].id);

        laser.animate(
          {
            left: targetX + ( targetW / 2 ),
            top: targetY + (targetH / 2),
            width: "0px"
          },
          {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "easeOutQuad",
            queue: true,
            complete: function() {
              console.log("laser fired!");

             laser.css(lasersCss[idx]);
              $laserBtn.css({
                textShadow:
                  "-1px -1px 0 #e5b13a, 1px -1px 0 #e5b13a, -1px 1px 0 #e5b13a, 1px 1px 0 #e5b13a"
              });
            }
          }
        );
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but it seems that only the top laser is properly positioned and rotated to to the right direction. Example: https://i.imgur.com/r7e1xLn.png